# How to add customized client side generated UUID for `_id` property in Elastic Search on Bulk Insert

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I am working with the Elasticsearch docker image version:  *docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.2*

To get ElasticSearch to accept a client side customized `UUID` on the `_id` field I had to change the: `"dynamic": "strict"` property to `true`.

All this time, we have been using strict and auto generated UUIDs for the `_id` field.

When inspecting, the newly inserted document, I noticed a new field is added: id whose contents are matched exactly onto the _id metadata field.

Is this the expected behaviour, is this right way of achieving what i set out to do, which is to generate UUIDs, client side and then push to ELASTIC via the bulk insert method.

I am using c# and the nest nuget package in dotnet 7.

Thanks for reading.

## Via Postman

When i try inserting a single document via postman:

[image]

You can see, the client side generated UUID is assigned to the `_id` field. Elastic just ignores the value and auto generates me a new one.

## Dto/Model Code

```
public interface IElasticDocumentId
{
    string id { get; set; }
}

public class SurfaceScanDocument : IElasticDocumentId
{
    public SurfaceScanDocument()
    {
        fs = new Fs();
    }
    public Fs fs { get; set; }

    public string id { get; set; }
    public string file_name { get; set; }
    public object file_type { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ingest { get; set; }
}
```

## Insert Nest Code:

```
        public async Task InsertDocumentWithId<T>(string indexName, T document) where T : class, IElasticDocumentId
    {
        try
        {
            var client = _elasticSearchClientProvider.GetElasticClient();
            var indexResponse = await client.IndexAsync(document, i => i
                .Index(indexName)
                .Id(document.id)
                .Refresh(Refresh.True));

            if (!indexResponse.IsValid)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error to insert document: {indexResponse.DebugInformation}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got this working, now, i will post an update shortly.

Answer (score 0):

## TDLR;

No, this is not the expected behaviour.
The `_id` is a metadatafield it should not be part of the mapping.

So you should not have to set the `dynamic: true`.

## Solution

To ingets a document while setting the `_id` you should do:

```json
POST 77646387/_doc/1
{
  "some": "data"
}
```

When you search this document you should find

```json
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "77646387",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "some": "data"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With the bulk api it is quite close:

```json
POST _bulk
{"create": {"_index": "77646387", "_id": 2}}
{"some": "more data"}
```

I do not know about the .net lib tho.

Comment: Thank you for responding, how does this work when using the NEST SDK and the `BulkAll()` method.

Comment: Maybe show some code ?

Comment: i have updated the question with a csharp code sample i am using.